# Traversing a general tree in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree

I am attempting to traverse a general tree. For the purpose of this example, I have this struct to hold my child and parent relationships.

```
struct DataItem {
    int id;
    DataItem* root;
    vector<DataItem*> children;
};
```

In comparison to a binary tree traversal, I am not using a *left and *right, as there could be more than one node. To traverse the code, I am using these two methods, called constructMap and then traverseTree.

```
void traverseTree(std::vector<int>::iterator current, std::vector<int>::iterator end,
    std::vector<int>::iterator next, DataItem *root) {
    while (current != end) {
        DataItem *childNode;
        childNode->id = *current;
        childNode->root = root;
        if (*current + 1 == *next) {
            root->children.push_back(childNode);
        } else {
            // traverse the next tree
            traverseTree(++current, end, ++next, childNode);
        }
        ++next;
        ++current;
    }
}


void constructMap(std::vector<int>::iterator start, std::vector<int>::iterator end) {
    auto next = std::next(start, 1);
    DataItem *parentNode;
    parentNode->id = *start;
    parentNode->root = NULL;
    traverseTree(++start, end, ++next, parentNode);
    cout << " at the end " << endl;
}
```

I have yet to test the logic to see the traversal is actually functional, though I presume its not, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

After some commenting out, it turns that this occurs in the constructMap, when I invoke this call:

```
parentNode->id = *start;
```

If I do something like this instead:

```
int val = *start;
parentNode->id = val;
```

I am able to pass this segmentation fault and continue forward.

I am passing an iterator of a vector to my map to process, containing something like this: 1,3,4,5,7,8,10

```
constructMap(allNumbers.begin(), allNumbers.end());
```

Comment: *After some commenting out,* -- So you're not using a debugger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to access the uninitialized pointer `parentNode`. Maybe make this a simple object:

```
DataItem parentNode;
parentNode.id = *start;
parentNode.root = NULL;
traverseTree(++start, end, ++next, &parentNode);
```

Comment: tsandy is correct, I think. I am a bit concerned in seeing that start is used with std::next and the value is obtained directly from it after the fact. The point being that I do not remember off hand if std::next advances start or not.

Comment: @Andrew when I looked at the documentation for std::next, all that was mentioned is that the original pointer to the iterator is copied and incremented, as opposed to accessed and incremented

Comment: @Andrew if it would advance the pointer, it would be equivalent to operator++() and hence redundant. In fact I don't know of any standard library function that takes an iterator argument by non-const reference and mutates it.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use raw pointers if possible. Either use plain objects or smart pointers such as std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr.

Then to traverse the tree you could use a recursive lambda function. I made an example [program](https://godbolt.org/z/cveaq8T37)

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Node {
  Node(int id) : Id(id) {}
  int Id;
  vector<Node> Children;
};

int main(void) {
  int id{};
  Node n0(id++);
  n0.Children.emplace_back(id++);
  n0.Children.emplace_back(id++);
  n0.Children.emplace_back(id++);
  auto &n1 = n0.Children.back();
  n1.Children.emplace_back(id++);
  n1.Children.emplace_back(id++);
  n1.Children.emplace_back(id++);
  n1.Children.emplace_back(id++);
  auto &n2 = n1.Children.back();

  std::function<void(const Node &)> visit = [&](const Node &n) {
    std::cout << n.Id << "\n";
    for (const Node &c : n.Children) {
      visit(c);
    }
  };

  visit(n0);
}
```